# Criteria - DetachedCriteria in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria, grails-2.0

**FIRST QUESTION:**

I have the following domain class in my app:

```
class Test {

 ...
 String name
 static hasMany = [evaluationsTest: Evaluation]
 ...

}

class Evaluation {
 ...
 String testName
 Float testScore
 ...
}
```

I need to obtain the number of evaluations between a range of scores (example: evaluations with scores between 7-8 ) of a specific test.

With a criteria **I can obtain it correctly**:

```
def criteria = Test.createCriteria()
def example = criteria.list {
   eq 'name', params.test
   evaluationsTest {
      ge("testScore", 7 as Float)
      lt("testScore", 8 as Float)
   }
   projections {
      count()
   }
}
```

But I want to know a async search and for this reason I want to use a DetachedCriteria but **it does not work.**

```
DetachedCriteria detached = Test.where {
   name == params.test
   evaluationsTest {
      ge("testScore", 7 as Float)
      lt("testScore", 8 as Float)
   }
   .projections {
      count()
   }
} as DetachedCriteria

def result = detached.async.list()
```

**EDITED**: Solved with withCriteria() method.

**SECOND QUESTION:**

Besides, I have another doubt. I need to parallelize this code. How can I do the each fragment? I used to **task** but sometimes works and other times appears the error: **Array Index Out of Bounds Exception**

```
// Rows
def rows = []
def addRow = { name, value ->
    rows << [c: [[v: name], [v: value]]]
}
// Add departments
departments.each { department ->
    addRow(department.name, department.users.size())
}
def UDData = [cols: cols, rows: rows]
```

With this code (tasks), I obtain: Array index out of bounds

```
List queriesToExecute = []

// Add departments - Asynchronous/Multi-thread
departments.each { department ->
    def departmentTask = tasks {
        rows << [c: [[v: department.name], [v:department.users.size()]]]
     }
     queriesToExecute << departmentTask
 }
 waitAll(queriesToExecute)
```

Comment: what does "does not work" mean?  please add relevant errors/stacktraces/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason your query may be failing is because you're creating a *where* query instead of a *criteria* query, and *where* queries do not support projections very well. They work... but only sometimes. And you'd have to define them outside of the query, like so:

```
DetachedCriteria detached = Test.where {
   name == params.test
   evaluationsTest {
      ge("testScore", 7 as Float)
      lt("testScore", 8 as Float)
   }   
}.projections {
      count()
} as DetachedCriteria
```

But, you don't actually need a `DetachedCriteria` to perform an async query. You can do it with a *criteria* query:

```
def promise = Test.async.withCriteria() {
   eq 'name', params.test
   evaluationsTest {
      ge("testScore", 7 as Float)
      lt("testScore", 8 as Float)
   }
   projections {
      count()
   }
}

def result = promise.get()
```

### Collecting the departments concurrently

Here's an example of using GPars to collect the department data concurrently, without side-effects:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

def rows

withPool {
    rows = departments.collectParallel { department ->
        [c: [[v: department.name], [v:department.users.size()]]]
    }
}

def UDData = [cols: cols, rows: rows]
```

This is using fork-join. So the `Closure` is executed concurrently, and then the results are joined together.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that withCriteria() I can use async option. Now I have another doubt (please, see the second question).

Comment: I think the problem is that you're trying to append to a List from multiple threads. That's a no-no because an `ArrayList`, which is what you get with `def x = []` is not thread-safe. I'm rusty on GPars, but I know it's capable of doing what you're looking for. Maybe with parallel collections.

Comment: I used this example: https://dzone.com/articles/example-using-grails-promises but as I told sometimes works well and other times appears the error: Array Index Out of Bounds Exception

Comment: The difference between that code and yours is that yours has side effects; it adds to a list concurrently. Doing so can lead to issues like what you're experiencing. Where it works only sometimes.

Comment: I added an example for addressing this issue.

Comment: Thanks. It works!! What is the difference between Gpars, task/tasks, events and async (GORM)? Do all these options add concurrency grails?

Comment: Gpars is a Groovy framework which provides concurrency, and it's included in Groovy (as of some version). Grails tasks are, by default, actually Gpars promises behind the scenes. The async GORM API also uses Gpars promises by default. Events are provided by the Reactor framework, which uses the Observer design pattern to generate and respond to... stuff that happens.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. By last, I saw that a plugin exists in Grails: compile "org.grails.plugins:gpars:0.3" - Do I need yo add in BuildConfig? I use Grails 2.5.3.